# Swift 4 String Interpolation causing JAVA to throw a null pointer exception

Tags: swift

When I send parameters to a JAVA DAO using the attached Swift 4 method. It fails if the fields are populated from text fields using string interpolation, but if I have all the fields hard coded as part of the postString parameter everything works.

I have first attached the hard coded parameter string.  I then include the method with the preferred String interpolation parameter string.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 let postString = "password=Pepper28!&fName=Superbowl&zip=07042    
 &emailId=rGeorge@test.com&uType=U&secQuestion=favoritesports&secAnswer
 =football"
```

Now here is the code I'm trying to execute and the only change is the postString uses string interpolation.

```
 let passW: String = self.password.text as Any as! String
    let fname: String = self.fName.text as Any as! String
    let zipname: String = self.zipcode.text as Any as! String
    let emailname: String = self.email.text as Any as! String        
    let userTypeName: String = self.uType.text as Any as! String
    let secretQuestion:String = self.forgotQuestion.text as Any as! String
    let secretAnswer:String = self.answerToForgotQuestion.text as Any as! String


    let url = URL(string:"http://localhost:8080/webapi/myprofile")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: 
    "Content-Type") request.httpMethod = "POST"

   let postString = "password=\(passW)&fName=\(fname)&zip=\(zipname)&emailId=
   \(emailname)&uType=\(userTypeName)&secQuestion=\(secretQuestion)&secAnswer=
   \(secretAnswer)"


    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task1 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode 
        != 200 {print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task1.resume()
```

Comment: You should take some time before starting to code and read Apple Swift book. Note that textfield text property will never return nil so you can simply force unwrap it instead of casting it to Any and later force casting it to String: `password.text!` instead of `password.text as Any as! String`

Comment: Btw why don't you print the result of your string interpolation to figure out what's wrong

Comment: Thanks I have located my issue.  The Java DAO required a specific character for the uType field.  Once I hard coded "U" for user without allowing the user to set everything works perfectly.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` ... `password=Pepper28!` ... Putting a password in a query parameter.